# Postgres: copy errors when extra tab on tab delimited text file

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have the three statements below that all work until it hits a row with an extra tab at the end of the tab delimited text file that I am trying to import. 
Any way to tell Postgres to ignore extra tabs?

copy mara FROM 'c:/Postgres MME/AG00_MARA.txt' DELIMITER E'\t' NULL '' CSV HEADER;

copy mara FROM 'c:/Postgres MME/AG00_MARA.txt' DELIMITER E'\t' CSV HEADER;

copy mara FROM 'c:/Postgres MME/AG00_MARA.txt' WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER E'\t', NULL '', HEADER);

[Image of Notepad++ Where I see the extra tab at the end of the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJFmp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to ignore it, just fix your data by removing all the trailing tabs with regex `\t$`. For example in Linux:

```
sed -i 's/\t$//g' AG00_MARA.txt
```

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid, but where do I run such a statment/code?
I assume this isn't inside pgAdminIII.

Comment: sed is a standard and should come pre-installed with your linux. Though now that I take a closer look at your data I guess you could still use `\t$` in the programmer's notepad's find and replace if you turn on regex.